# Automatic alert on value change

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new. I have looked through many questions and answers and have tried all the solutions provided but to no avail.

In Excel 2010 I have 2 cells A1 and B1

A1's data is from a web source and contains numbers and letters.
B1 separates the numbers and letters and just displays the numbers.

I need to be alerted when the number in B1 increases or decreases. It seems a simple task but can't find a solution.

Comment: This will require VBA on the worksheet's `worksheet_change()` event. It's NOT easy, nor is it simple which is why you are having problems. The jist is that every time the value changes you have to compare the new value of that cell to the value of the cell where you stored the last change, then alert the user if there is a change, then store the new value so you can compare it next time it changes. A right-big pain in the butt.

Comment: @JNevill It's even more painful than that. The `Worksheet_Change()` event only fires when a value is entered into a cell, not when a data source refresh changes the value of a cell.

Comment: Try this: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(): MsgBox "Cell B1 updated: " & Me.Range("B1"): End Sub`

Comment: @JNevill  & teylyn .. thanks for the responses and the reasurrances that i'm not going mad and that its not as simple as it seems to solve. I have tried the code kindly provided by paul bica but I get the error 'Method or data member not found' which i believe is Error 461 .VBA also highlights 'Range' .

Comment: Why are you putting solutions in Comments when they should be Answers?